# Enable Auto-updates for all plugins using wp-cli? (since wordpress 5.5)

Tags: wp-cli, automatic-updates

Since WP 5.5 just released and now you can set plugins to auto-update, can this be done via wp-cli?
Looking at the documentation, I don't see a sub-command for it: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/

I manage a lot of Wordpress sites, most of which are OK to auto-update and would save me a lot of time if they did, as well as reducing security risks.

I'd like to enable auto-updates for plugins across over many wordpress sites. Any solutions?

Comment: Sounds like a feature request to https://github.com/wp-cli/extension-command

Comment: Interesting question. I also manage a pile of WP sites, and use the excellent "Infinite WP" plugin to manage them; installing updates on all sites with just one click. Have used it for a couple of years, and it's well-maintained and supported. But a function to set all plugins to auto-update would be interesting.

Comment: @leymannx I have submitted a feature request. Thank you!

Comment: @RickHellewell thanks for the information. I will look into that plugin. To date I was using the Easy Update Manager plugin, but this does not allow granular control from one dashboard for all sites. Although I would prefer this option was built into wordpress.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking to do using wp-cli, but from the WordPress Admin Plugins page, you can select all plugins and choose the bulk action of "Enable auto-updates"

Comment: Yes, that feature is now in the latest WP. But not available when question and comment was entered. @MikeEng - you should put your comment as the answer, for those that wander by here.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way via *wp-cli* that comes to mind (<s>while it's not supported yet as far as I can see</s>) is something like:

```
wp eval "update_option( 'auto_update_plugins', array_keys( get_plugins() ) );"
```

that will update the `auto_update_plugins` option with the array of all plugin files to update.

This should probably be extended further to only update plugins that are truly *updateable* or e.g. from a json list to use the json format option of *wp-cli*.

One can also enable all plugin updates with a filter in a plugin:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
```

That will show up as "Auto-updates enabled" for each plugin in the plugins admin table but the user will not be able to change it from the UI.

ps: this *wp-cli* [command suggestion](https://github.com/WordPress/wp-autoupdates/issues/8) by Jeffrey Paul seems very useful.

**Update**: This seems to be supported in [wp-cli/extension-command](https://github.com/wp-cli/extension-command) version 2.0.12 by this [pull request](https://github.com/wp-cli/extension-command/pull/259):

```
wp plugin auto-updates status [<plugin>...] [--all] [--enabled-only] [--disabled-only] [--field=<field>]
wp plugin auto-updates enable [<plugin>...] [--all] [--disabled-only]
wp plugin auto-updates disable [<plugin>...] [--all] [--enabled-only]
```

but it looks like it's not merged into the main *wp-cli* yet in version 2.4.

It's possible to get the latest version with:

```
wp package install git@github.com:wp-cli/extension-command.git
```

according to the [installing](https://github.com/wp-cli/extension-command#installing) part of the *wp-cli/extension-command* docs.

Comment: I see "eval", I panic ;D

Comment: The editor should play ["Danger, Will Robinson!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWwOJlOI1nU) when that word is found in the text :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not using wp-cli, but maybe the next best thing:

From the Plugins page in WordPress Admin: siteurl.com/wp-admin/plugins.php

You can check all plugins and then from the bulk actions, choose “enable auto updates”.

[image: enable auto updates]